# Android Image preview animation similar to facebook

Tags: android

I want to use animation for full screen image preview similar to Facebook. When user clicks on image, vertical transition animation occurs and image resizes to device full screen.(Same when we click on the image from newsfeed page in facebook).

I tried to use Fresco library for the same but there are some integration problems. Can anyone suggest for solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into Translate Animation and Scale Animation, though there are many libraries that might make it easier.

Comment: Official sample: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Comment: I want to use library similar to [IDMPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/ideaismobile/IDMPhotoBrowser) for android

Comment: @JiTHiN: Thanks...This sample works as aspected.

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook Rebound Library](http://facebook.github.io/rebound/) does the animation that you want, but you have to implement your own code to make it work.

Here is the Facebook Rebound Library Example in action.

[image: Facebook Origami Example]

You can check out the [Example Code](https://github.com/facebook/rebound/tree/master/rebound-android-playground) at Facebook Github Profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set xml for zooming a view. adjust yours bounds and you can zoom your view from its position to any much extent you want .Here is a working example. change the values of pivotX and pivotY as you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fillAfter="true" > 
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="20%"
    android:pivotY="20%"
    android:toXScale="0.8"
    android:toYScale="0.8" >
</scale>

</set>
```